will it fail if the program tried to create an account with the same seeds multiple times , although the bump exists ? using anchor

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
            AMM_CONFIG_SEED.as_bytes()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        space = 8 + AmmConfig::INIT_SPACE,
    )]
    pub amm_config: Account<'info, AmmConfig>,



as shown here, the seed is constant , but the program uses a bump which varies to get a valid PDA address , so if I called this instruction to create this account amm_config multiple times , will it fail or success ??
The PDA will be created with the same program ID and the same seed; will it fail or pass?

it will fail with an error "account already in use". Same seed = same address. You can't create an account that already exists.
If your seed is constant like this, why not creating the account first, and then remove the init ?
